# Can you combine different string functions together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function

I'm trying to turn a string into lowercase and then count the amount of times a letter appears in that string using Python.

Am I allowed to combine both string functions together? Or is this frowned upon or completely wrong because it does seem to work fine:

```
name2 = name1.lower().count("a")
```

Comment: If something works, you don‘t have to ask if it‘s OK, especially if it‘s something this short.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that this wouldn't be allowed?

Comment: That is more than allowed, it is expected and possibly preferred.  That's why so many object methods return a compatible object, so they are chainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you may chain several calls together in the manner you mentioned. It is both syntactically correct and Pythonic (conforms to normal conventions of using the Python language.)